# Difference between UPSERT and MERGE?

Tags: postgresql, merge, terminology, upsert

From the PostgreSQL wiki,

> `MERGE` is typically used to merge two tables, and was introduced in the 2003 SQL standard. The `REPLACE` statement (a MySQL extension) or *UPSERT* sequence attempts an `UPDATE`, or on failure, `INSERT`. This is similar to `UPDATE`, then for unmatched rows, `INSERT`. Whether concurrent access allows modifications which could cause row loss is implementation independent.

Further PostgreSQL's [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29) is marketed as *UPSERT* and was added in 9.5

What then is `MERGE`? And how does it fit into the mix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally,

- `UPSERT` is built off of `INSERT`
- `MERGE` focuses on merging/synchronizing tables and provides

  - *conditionality* (where clauses)
  - `DELETE` support.

`UPSERT` lacks conditionality, In PostgreSQL, you had some ability to specify conditions, by proxy of the index that was being violated, for instance

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT countries_pkey DO NOTHING;
ON CONFLICT (country) DO NOTHING;
```

But it didn't provide the ability to specify multiple conditions nor the ability to `DELETE` in any condition, both of which permit a more rich set of rules making it possible to "synchronize tables with minimal work" which seems to be the goal of `MERGE`.

As another matter, from [Peter Geoghegan's post highlighting some of the differences *"SQL `MERGE` is quite distinct from UPSERT"*](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAM3SWZRP0c3g6+aJ=YYDGYAcTZg0xA8-1_FCVo5Xm7hrEL34kw@mail.gmail.com)

- UPSERT is atomic in its *insert-or-update*
- SQL MERGE doesn't technically require a UNIQUE INDEX.

## See also

- [PostgreSQL patch returned 9/11](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/20/1446/)
- [PostgreSQL 11 `MERGE` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-merge.html) (since removed)